# Windows remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, windows

I want to login into a Windows server with remote desktop but I want to do that in a way that
the user view what I'm doing like do vnc server.

How can I do?

In default mode remote desktop disconnect the user and give the remote user full access to the machine...

Comment: Is someone physically at the server at the same time you want to interact with the screen or is this two remote connections?

Comment: there is someone phisically and I want that he see what I'm doing.

Comment: "In default mode remote desktop disconnect the user and give the remote user full access to the machine..." - On a workstation, not on a server. What is this server you are referring to?

Answer (score 6):

If you want a built-in solution Windows [Remote Assistance](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/helpandsupport/learnmore/remoteassist/intro.mspx) may be what you want.  It allows you to remotely control a machine or RDP session while the user still is connected.

Past that, there are lots of third part remote control applications.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the `shadow` command. There are a few options that must be set for it to work and an option that must be turned off to prevent the session you're viewing from being prompted. See this Microsoft help article: "[How to Shadow a Terminal Server Session Without Prompt for Approval](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292190)" as well as [Microsoft KB article 278845](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278845).

EDIT: I do admit that this is not as user-friendly as some other solutions. However, if you're dead set against installing anything new on the server it would work. For friendlier options, check out [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx), [CrossLoop](http://www.crossloop.com/index.jsp) or even [Bomgar](http://www.bomgar.com/) gear.

EDIT #2: In light of new information, since you want to have someone that is physically at the server see what you're doing you have several options. you can use a third party tool like teamviewer. However, if you don't want to install anything new, the person that you're instructing will have to log into the server and then you'll need to remote into the server with Remote Desktop and then use the Shadow command on session 0. A final option is if you have some kind of remote management card such as HP's iLO.

Answer (score 0):

"Remote Tools" in Microsoft SMS duplicates VNC functionality.  It is similar to Remote Assistance but does not prompt the user before allowing you to view and interact with their session.

I am not sure if this functionality can be duplicated outside of SMS.

[Remote Tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723617.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a server, as you've indicated by the use of the "windows-server" tag, rather than a workstation, why not simply shadow (remote control) the other user. That way you both see exactly the same screen and can share use of the keyboard and mouse.

If it's a workstation please retag the question appropriately and use Remote Assistance, as Zoredache has already answered.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you might want is code named "tahiti" and is currently called (at least until the marketing morons decide to rename to something inane) [sharedview](https://connect.microsoft.com/site94).  Its currently available on the connect site. with sharedview up to 15 people can view your desktop and interact with you (but not the desktop unless you transfer control).  Remote assist is the best option if it's another users desktop that you want access to while they watch.